# GAE users authentication doesn't work from iphone for channel_API

Tags: iphone, google-app-engine, channel-api

I have a GAE app that works just fine from my browser, but can't figure out the user when I try to run the same website on the iphone.
I'm using the current user_id to send a message with the channel-API

This is the code in my python GAE app - here are two defs - send_update, and send_update_iphone - as you see they are totally similar! both are in the Class Updater():

```
Updater():
     def send_update(self):
        message = self.get_fetch_message()
        user = users.get_current_user()
        channel.send_message(user.user_id()+user.user_id(),message)



    #for iphone - no user yet...
    def send_update_iphone(self):
        message = self.get_fetch_message()
        user = users.get_current_user()
        channel.send_message(user.user_id()+user.user_id(),message)
```

Now, I call them from different places, I call the first

```
Updater().send_update()
```

and the second

```
Updater().send_update_iphone()
```

When I use the application the first works beautifully - it opens the channel, and updates it on messages without a problem.
when I get to the app from the iphone (whilst logged-in to my gmail) I get:

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'user_id'

few details for the iPhone side:
- I get to the website from UIWebView
- I can see I'm logged-in to my google account

Can someone help? I tried anything I know >>> Thanks!

UPDATE: I checked the cookies (thanks Calvin) and saw that on the browser I get a cookie, but in the iphone I don't get a cookie (I use `NSLog(@"Cookies: %@", [request1 responseCookies]);`  )

I now know that in the browser it works because I get in the myapp.appspot.com page from my browser, so that's why it has the cookie, whilst from the iphone i POST to myapp.appspot.com, but I never get in the page itself, so the server never send me the cookie.
That's interesting, but I still don't know how to solve...

Comment: You should print out what cookies are set in each situation. I think using a UIWebView within an app gives you a separate set of cookies from Mobile Safari. Also, is the logged in gmail user going through the App Engine login prompt? That's what sets the cookie used by get_current_user.

Comment: Hi, I checked the cookies - will update the question.

Comment: But what is App Engine login prompt? do you mean that I'm supposed to get a "login" page from gae? because I don't, and I use the method showed in the GAE documentation for login, and redirect, etc. Maybe you have a different example for the login method I could use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what the problem was: the iphone didn't authenticate as a user, because I forgot to put the  "`if not user:`

```
    self.redirect(users.create_login_url(self.request.uri))
```

in the page that I requested the iphone to direct to (myapp.appspot.com/iphone). So of course when there was no user the user.get_current_user() replied with:

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'user_id'

What I do now is that I load the UIWebView first to go to myapp.appspot.com/iphone - to make sure that if the user haven't logged in, he will, and then redirect to wherever I need.